# Make GHC apply basic math laws on `KnownNat`

Tags: haskell, types, linear-algebra, type-safety

i just discovered the super awesome Haskell library `Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Static` from the [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix) package.

Now i implemented a function that shall transform a matrix A to a vector B and another matrix C like this:

```
    1 2 3
A = 4 5 6
    7 8 9

B = 2 3

C = 5 6
    8 9
```

the code that i came up with that successfully compiles looks like this:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Static

f :: (KnownNat (n + 1), KnownNat n, 1 <= n + 1, ((n + 1) - 1) ~ n)
  => Sq (n + 1) -> (R n, Sq n)
f m = (unrow a, b)
    where
        (a, b) = splitRows . snd . splitCols $ m

main :: IO ()
main = print $ f $ (matrix [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] :: Sq 3)
```

Now this works well, but i hope that i can remove seemingly redundant things like `((n + 1) - 1) ~ n` from the type signature.

Is it somehow possible to make GHC accept a signature like `f :: Sq (n + 1) -> (R n, Sq n)` without anything else? Or at least something like `f :: (KnownNat n, 2 <= n) => Sq n -> (R (n - 1), Sq (n - 1))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are type checking plugins that can do this.  Specifically, `ghc-typelits-natnormalise` can figure out that `((n + 1) - 1) ~ n` and `1 <= n + 1`, while `ghc-typelits-knownnat` can figure out that `KnownNat n` implies `KnownNat (n+1)`.  So, with both packages installed, you can write:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fplugin GHC.TypeLits.KnownNat.Solver #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fplugin GHC.TypeLits.Normalise #-}

import GHC.TypeLits
import Numeric.LinearAlgebra.Static

f :: (KnownNat n) => Sq (n + 1) -> (R n, Sq n)
f m = (unrow a, b)
    where
        (a, b) = splitRows . snd . splitCols $ m

main :: IO ()
main = print $ f $ (matrix [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] :: Sq 3)
```

The `KnownNat n` constraint is unavoidable.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.